# An Xenon I and two other destroyers are headed straight for Heretic's End. What can I do?

Tags: x4-foundations

A Xenon `I` is in Wretched Skies on its way to the Heretic's End gate. There's two more destroyers behind it.

[image: Xenon I about to wreck Boso Ta]

I'm 3 days into a game, have been doing various storylines, and am extremely poor. I have the Cradles of Humanity Katana and a Thresher. The Katana lets me get onto the I's back, but doesn't even scratch the shield, much less the paint.

Is there anything I can do?

---

##### Update

Based on [@philipp](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/35432/philipp)'s answer, I evacuated Heretic's End and Morningstar III, in case they are mad at the Argon and want to turn that direction instead of wrecking me.

The `I` is caught up on stations in Wretched Skies V, but hasn't stumbled on the defense platform that could keep them out of Heretic's End yet.

[image: Xenon I wrecking Wretched Skies V]

I used the Katana to disable one of the two `K`s in Wretched Skies X, and called in the Thresher to help finish it off, which took about half an hour of hammering on the XL shield generators.

[image: Xenon K destroyed in Wretched Skies X]

---

##### Update 2

The `I` engaged with the defense platform. The Thresher and I are destroying the other `K`.

[image: Xenon I near defense platform]

... and has been destroyed. Meanwhile the Thresher and I haven't even gotten the last disabled `K` down to 80% shields yet.

[image: Xenon I is scrap]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably not much you can do about it at this point in the game.

But don't worry. Sooner or later, the AIs will manage to destroy the invaders and then start to replace any stations they destroyed with new ones. Which will, by the way, create a huge demand for claytronics, hull parts and other station construction wares. An opportunity you can use to make a lot of money.

In the meantime, make sure you evacuate any valuable assets you have in that sector and use the "global orders" to blacklist the sectors under Xenon incursion so your automated traders don't run into them.